# C# FirstOrDefault() return null even with element existing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following code that needs to return a single value. However, I keep on getting null (the field `Notifications_Id = 0`) even though it clearly exists in the database.

```
var role = _context.AssignedTickets.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Notifications_Id == incidence.Notifications_Id);
```

I am using Net Core 5

[image: Notifications_Id returning 0]

Below is my code

```
public async Task<ActionResult> EditTicket(int? id)
    {
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return StatusCode(400);
            }
            Incidence incidence = await _context.Incidences.FindAsync(id);
            if (incidence == null)
            {
                return StatusCode(401);
            }
            return View(incidence);
        }
    }

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult EditTicket(Incidence incidence)
    {
var role = _context.AssignedTickets.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Notifications_Id == incidence.Notifications_Id);

        if (role == null)
        {
            return StatusCode(404);
        }
        role.Status = "C";

        role.ClosedOn = DateTime.Now;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            DateTime Timeup = (DateTime)role.ClosedOn;
            DateTime Timedown = (DateTime)role.CreatedOn;
            long DiffTicks = (Timedown - Timeup).Ticks;
            role.TurnAroundTime = Math.Abs(DiffTicks).ToString();

            _context.Entry(incidence).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Agent");
        }

        return View(incidence);
    }
```

Comment: The code seems correct. Are you sure you have an AssignedTicket with Id == 0?

Comment: Make sure your connection string is correct. Make a trial by load all `AssignedTicket` into memory check whether data is loaded or not

Comment: @xrodas No actually the existing ticket is with Id - 29. I don't understand where the 0 is coming from while on the db the same field has the 29

Comment: @Nickson If you expect an Id = 29 in your incidence instance then I suspect you are not reading this instance correctly from the database. Perhaps, you have created a new Incidence and, by default, it gets the Id = 0

Comment: How can we replicate this issue, please update your post to include a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @zaggler Changes made

Comment: How is `incidence` getting hydrated? Is this from a form post? Json? Or being called from another  method?

Comment: check with hardcoded value to confirm if its going to database to fetch the data

Answer (score 0):

Please use var `role = _context.AssignedTickets.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Notifications_Id == 29)`; to get the object, and then compare whether the attributes inside match the database.

I read your post and all comments carefully. What everyone said is very reasonable, and the code in the post is not problematic.

***So I think the problem is likely to be a problem with the string connecting to the database, that is, a different database is used.***